# Unity game object is not moving foward. (Space Shooter)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new to Unity so I am just getting used to all the libraries and such. I am trying to create a space shooter game and now in the process of creating the bullets. I could now spawn the bullet, the problem now is that it is not moving forward with respect to the ship I have. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Here is the Code:

```
using UnityEngine;
```

using System.Collections;

public class Projectile : MonoBehaviour {

```
public Rigidbody projectile;
//GameObject prefab = Resources.Load ("sphere") as GameObject;

public float speed = 20;



/*// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}*/

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
    {
        Rigidbody instantiatedProjectile = Instantiate(projectile,
            projectile.position,
            projectile.rotation)
            as Rigidbody;

        instantiatedProjectile.velocity = transform.TransformDirection(new Vector3(0, 0,speed));

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Instead of transform direction, use transform.Forward() * Speed;
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-forward.html

Also, take a look at [this link](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-velocity.html), as you should try to ApplyForces instead of modifying velocity directly

Comment: Didn't do the trick. All it does is it spawns the bullet then just leaves it there in place

Comment: Make sure IsKinematic is set to false

Comment: Yeah I tried that.  Still same result. Might just start all over

Comment: Are you sure the code is being executed and running without errors?

Answer (score 0):

You want to Apply a force to the bullets rigidbody using Rigidbody.ApplyForce();

Also, your code currently displays poor OO architecture, so I would also suggest creating a new script on either an empty gameObject or the spaceship, which will manage the player input. and then just having the projectile manage the bare necessities. For instance:

```
// Attached to Either empty GO or spaceship GO
public class PlayerInput : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject spaceship;
    public GameObject bulletPrefab;
    public float projectileSpeed;
    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        {
            GameObject newBullet = Instantiate(bulletPrefab, spaceship.transform.position, new Quaternion()) as GameObject;
            newBullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(spaceship.transform.forward * projectileSpeed);
        }
    }
}

// Attached to Either Projectile GO
public class Projectile : MonoBehaviour {

    void OnCollisionEnter()
    {
        Debug.Log("Boom");
    }

}
```

Also note that you may need to tweak the rigidbody attributes in order to get the desired effect, such as for instance disabling gravity.

Comment: I tried this method, and it still gave me the same result.